# Create CSV from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Hello I have an array in PHP that looks like the following :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20140723,8,156.62,LTD.
20140418-23,16-4010061201,936-438-2501,Y,23,20140418,V849,10.00
20140418-29,16-4010091102,936-438-2501,Y,29,20140418,V849,2.00
0,16-4010091102,936-436-0524,works.com,Y,0,20140723,0,0
0,16-4010061201,936-438-2501,waterw.com,Y,0,20140723,0,0
0,16-4010091102,936-438-2501,waterworks.com,Y,0,20140723,0,0
    [1] => 140723-1548.csv
)
```

What I would like to do is to create a csv file that has as content the first index of the array above and as title the second array index. I used the following function :

```
function createCSV($Myarray, $filename){
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fputcsv($fp, array($Myarray)); 
    fclose($fp);  
}
```

and I called it like that :

```
createCSV($Myarray[0], $Myarray[1]);//$Myarray is the array above
```

the problem I have is that the first cell in the csv output has all the data from the first index of the array, what I would like is to have each first index array line in a row in the csv.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put each cell in its own index of the array? That would make more sense.

Comment: 0 is that one row in the csv? multiple rows? how are they delimited ?

Comment: can explain more what you mean please?

Comment: this is supposed to be the first row in the csv output : 20140418-23,16-4010061201,936-438-2501,Y,23,20140418,V849,10.00   my issue is that I have this entire line in  one cell

Comment: are there real line breaks in the string? how do you know when a row ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code

```
 function createCSV($Myarray, $filename){
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fputcsv($fp, split(',',$Myarray)); 
    fclose($fp);  
 }
```

or simply

```
function createCSV($Myarray, $filename){
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fputs($fp, $Myarray); 
    fclose($fp);  
 }
```

explaination:

fputcsv creates one cell in the csv for corresponding array elements irrespective of the data in he array. in your case you are just passing one array element with comma seperated string as value. fputcsv is behaving correctly to make only a single csv column. so either user fput or split the data in multiple array elements

Comment: Hi, thanks it is working as i want , you should change fput to fputs because there is no fput in PHP